Should I accept this fraudulent job?
I work as a subcontractor for a major company for $22/hr. Minimal benefits, no PTO of any kind, etc.
I just got contacted for an interview w/a different sub-contractor at $30/hr for clearly the exact same job; except that it's under 1099, which I know for a fact would qualify for payroll fraud (nothing about the job would fit under "independent contractor").
Should I go ahead with the interview? Would it be feasible to accept the job and immediately take them to court for payroll fraud?

Why would you do this? Take the job and then take them to court? That makes no sense. What would you hope to accomplish? Why do you think this would be payroll fraud, whatever that is? Do you mean that you believe they would misclassify you as a contractor rather than an employee? None of what you've written makes much sense as written.

"which I know for a fact would qualify for payroll fraud" - seems to me that besides contractor you are also a lawyer to know this for a fact?

It doesn't take a lawyer to know that being required to work 40 hours per week, onsite, with a company-issued laptop doesn't qualify for 1099/independent contractor designation.

Why would you accept the job and then take them to court for payroll fraud? What would you hope to accomplish? This makes no sense to me.

VTC - "should I do this" question is about a specific choice.

@Virgil I've seen cases (not on the US tho) where a "contractor works the regular 40h week, on site, with company laptop". It happens when that company wants/needs the contractor to be on site. For example, access to a critical server can only be done on-site.

@DarkCygnus I'm familiar with the job, as I already have it through a different subcontracting agency. It can be done remotely.

If you can get a raise for doing this, why not? This doesn't sound like fraud of any kind. It sounds more like one contractor trying to push out another. It is possible that the contractor offering you the job won't get it.

Would it be feasible to accept the job and immediately take them to court for payroll fraud? What would you gain from that? What damages can you claim? Just want to expose them?


Should I go ahead with the interview?

I'd give them the benefit of doubt (who know, perhaps you are misunderstanding something) and go ahead with the interview.
It's better payment and perhaps you were just misunderstanding and don't want to let a better opportunity go.
I suggest that you go ahead, and during the interview perhaps ask a bit more about the nature of the contract and the 1099 etc., that way you will know for sure if your fear is true and if (according to your knowledge) its fraud and decide to back off.
I'd also suggest you "check yourself", and why this triggered your alerts about fraud. I must say I'm no expert on US employment laws, and chances are you are neither, which strengthens my point that perhaps you are misunderstanding something.
Perhaps consulting with a lawyer or someone versed in US employment laws is something you want to do before attending the interview.

Would it be feasible to accept the job and immediately take them to court for payroll fraud?

This seems very far-fetched (you got me raising my eyebrow) and I would not suggest doing that.

when I read the following line:

I work as a subcontractor for a major company for $22/hr. Minimal
benefits, no PTO of any kind, etc.

That sounds like you are a 1099 contractor.  That $22/hr is supposed to be your pay for the actual hours you work, and to cover your benefits live PTO, insurances, social security. holidays, and retirement.

I just got contacted for an interview w/a different sub-contractor at
$30/hr for clearly the exact same job; except that it's under 1099,
which I know for a fact would qualify for payroll fraud (nothing about
the job would fit under "independent contractor").

It sounds like your current client has been treating you as a W-2, but not wanting to give you much in the way of benefits.
Almost any job could be done as a 1099 or W-2 if the scheduling is done correctly.
From one of your comments:

It doesn't take a lawyer to know that being required to work 40 hours
per week, onsite, with a company-issued laptop doesn't qualify for
1099/independent contractor designation.

Sometimes they need you to use their equipment. They don't want random computers hooking to their network.
Now on your your question.
Your plan is to accept the offer from the new company, quit your old job, start at the new company and then file a claim. The end result could be unemployment. The old company doesn't have to take you back.

No. I know this job, and it absolutely cannot be a 1099 rather than a W2. Per the gov't's own definition. The work is not results based, but hourly (and not in the legal industry) with organized (if poorly) training & delegation. There are no expenses on my part. It can be done remotely, but the 1099 position restricts the work to be in their office, with no difference in company laptop.
https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/independent-contractor-self-employed-or-employee
